# How to resolve a table by table name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
declare @table nvarchar(max) = 'dbo.Person';
insert into @table (name)
values ('Test')
```

Is this possible with some advanced SQL wizardry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it use `exec`

```
declare @table nvarchar(max) = 'dbo.Person';
exec (' INSERT INTO '+@table + ' ([name]) values (''Test'')');
```

---

you can read more details from [EXECUTE (Transact-SQL) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: it's my pleasure : )